# Libraries to convert xml into JSON and vice versa

Tags: xml, json, xslt

I need to transform one document formated in xml into JSON and vice versa.

I belive this is a common requirement and perhaps there's still one library that does that work.

Know any?

Comment: Good Question (+1). See my answer for an available XSLT solution of converting accessing JSON to XML directly from XSLT.

Comment: @nabo: does it matter if it's written in C#? What if it were written in VB.NET, but you could call it from C# or any other .NET language?

Comment: @John Saunders - You're right, i will remove the C# label. It can be in any language since i could import a dll to use in C#.

Comment: @nabo: I already edited to remove the "C#". That was just a "heads-up" so you know it's preferred not to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [Json.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/).  It's a great library that is easy to get into.

Answer (score 1):

Not a C#, but **a pure XSLT 2.0 implementation** that converts a JSON object into an XML document:

Have a look at the [**`f:json-document()`**](http://fxsl.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/fxsl/fxsl-xslt2/f/func-json-document.xsl?view=markup&sortby=date) from the [**FXSL 2.x library**](http://fxsl.sf.net).

Using this function it is extremely easy to incorporate JSon and use it just as... XML.

For example, one can just write the following XPath expression:

```
f:json-document($vstrParam)/Students/*[sex = 'Female']
```

and **get all children of `Students` with `sex = 'Female'`**

**Here is the complete example:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
 xmlns:f="http://fxsl.sf.net/"
 exclude-result-prefixes="f xs"
 >
 <xsl:import href="../f/func-json-document.xsl"/>

 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vstrParam" as="xs:string">
{

  "teacher":{
    "name":
      "Mr Borat",
    "age":
      "35",
    "Nationality":
      "Kazakhstan"
             },


  "Class":{
    "Semester":
      "Summer",
    "Room":
      null,
    "Subject":
      "Politics",
    "Notes":
      "We're happy, you happy?"
           },

  "Students":
    {
      "Smith":
        {"First Name":"Mary","sex":"Female"},
      "Brown":
        {"First Name":"John","sex":"Male"},
      "Jackson":
        {"First Name":"Jackie","sex":"Female"}
    }
    ,


  "Grades":

    {
      "Test":
      [
        {"grade":"A","points":68,"grade":"B","points":25,"grade":"C","points":15},

        {"grade":"C","points":2, "grade":"B","points":29, "grade":"A","points":55},

        {"grade":"C","points":2, "grade":"A","points":72, "grade":"A","points":65}
       ]
    }


}
 </xsl:variable>

 <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:sequence select=
     "f:json-document($vstrParam)/Students/*[sex = 'Female']"/>

 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When the above transformation is applied on any XML document (ignored), the correct result is produced**:

```
<Smith>
   <First_Name>Mary</First_Name>
   <sex>Female</sex>
</Smith>
<Jackson>
   <First_Name>Jackie</First_Name>
   <sex>Female</sex>
</Jackson>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about from json to xml, but we use this xml to json xsl template to great effect in out CMS which is XML based, rather handy to reuse existing XML structures for ajax applications.

http://code.google.com/p/xml2json-xslt/