# Giving incorrect values when converting JSON string to XML and XML back to JSON string

Tags: java, xml, json

I am using org.json for converting the json string to xml and xml back to json. I am getting the expected response for json string which has only key value pairs, but incase of json string contains of jsonarray objects the return value is different from the input?
Below the code i have used,

```
    import org.json.JSONObject;
    import org.json.XML;

    String jsonStr ="........";
    System.out.println("The JSON Raw Text :"+ jsonStr);
    JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
    String xml = org.json.XML.toString(jObject);
    JSONObject xmlJSONObj = XML.toJSONObject(xml);
    String jsonConvertString = xmlJSONObj.toString();
    System.out.println("JSON text converted : "+jsonConvertString);
```

What is the error or what is the best way to convert json string to xml and back to json ?

Comment: You can start by looking it up in [google](http://www.google.com) here is a link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2916495/libraries-to-convert-xml-into-json-and-vice-versa

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are facing problem as explained in [this blog](http://www.coderanch.com/t/628876/java-io/java/Converting-Json-XML-Generated-invalid).

In short: `XML.toString()` does NOT produce an XML document. When you use a JSONArray the produced xml string from this method has NO root element.

Therefore, if you are planning to write the contents to an XML file, I'll recommend you use a more stringent API such as `org.w3c.dom.*`. This will produce a VALID xml document that can be dumped to a file.

Or an easier way would be use something like `"<root>" + org.json.XML.toString(jArray) + "</root>"` so that you have a root element. This might be parsed pretty well (and as you expect) by `XML.toJSONObject()`.